# Как написать условие выбора для калькулятора?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется калькулятор, в нем пишется некоторые детали и в итоге по формуле выводится
общая стоимость `<p id="summ"></p>`

```
"results":[{"id":"1","name":"<p>Сумма:<\/p>","name_text":"Сумма:","formula":"A×B×D+(H×I)×K+L+(M×N)×O+(P+R)×S+(T×U)+(Y×Z)","pref":"<p>&nbsp;Р.<\/p>","pref_text":" Р","sum_start":"<p>","sum_end":"<\/p>"}],
```

В общем вывод происходит в `<p id="summ">2000</p>`
Как написать условие, чтобы оно брало это значение внутри этого

и в зависимости от значения выводил определенный div.

пример: если общая сумма вышла больше 200, выводила `id="block1"`
если больше 300, то `id="block2"`

Answer (score 2):

```
function output(){
    var summ=parseInt($("#summ").html());
    // дальше проверка условий 
    if(summ<=200){
        //выводите блок со своим id1
    }else if(summ<300){
        //выводите блок со своим id2
    }
    ..........
}
```

ну и соответственно запускаете функцию, после выполнения рассчета калькулятора.

Comment: в `else if` первое условие лишнее.